# google checkout sandbox buyer and seller account

Tags: google-checkout

I  am  developer implementing Google checkout payment gateway for my client .I have  a problem  in   making a test account  for buyer
 https://sandbox.google.com/checkout
and  for seller  when i go  to the  following URL.
sandbox buyer account at https://sandbox.google.com/checkout

the   following error  will  occur:
503. That’s an error.
The service you requested is not available at this time.
Service error -27. That’s all we know.

I also   have a  gmail account .Can  i use this  in making  sandbox buyer and seller  account.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue today.

After a couples of tries and some guesses, I got it working.

Instead of https://sandbox.google.com/checkout,
go to this link: https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/

The only difference is that the second link has an extra forward-slash.

Hope it helps.

Thank you. : )

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the links mention by you in question.
This error is occur due to some reasons. 
Reasons may be as following:

1. Due to the slow connection of internet.
2. you need to Login on Gmail on same browser in new tab.
3. Have you try it by refreshing the URL two three times.

May be these problems are there with you. So try again to access this URL.

For more help check this link: [Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox)